# commutator subgroups and isomorphic

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let G and H be finitely generated groups. Let G' = [G,G] and H' = [H,H] be the corresponding derived groups (commutator subgroups) of G and H. we know that there exist groups  G and H such that G' is isomorphic to H' and G/G' is isomorphic to H/H' but G and H are not isomorphic. with which additional condition on G,H  can we obtain G and H  are isomorphic? (for example residually finite, FC-group, m-generators with n-expanent,...)

Comment: Certainly residual finiteness is not enough. For instance, consider a semi-direct product $\Gamma_\phi=\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}$, where the eigenvalues of $\phi$ are real and distinct. Then $\Gamma_\phi$ is residually finite with $[\Gamma_\phi,\Gamma_\phi]\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the abelianisation isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ but $\Gamma_\phi$ and $\Gamma_\psi$ are isomorphic if and only if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-conjugate. 

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo - the commutator subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: I think that there exist finite groups $G, H$ with $G'\cong H'$ and
$G/G' \cong H/H'$, but $G, H$ are not isomorphic. So all your additional conditions, as finiteness conditions, are not enough. 

Comment: I think $Q_8$ and $D_8$ are such examples.

Answer (score 4):

Wei Zhou's answer already gives a very good example and I agree with the above comments. **However** for a "way out" - I want to give you two classes of obtacles, if you additionally remove the first, you're on your way to a well-known equivalence, which is weaker than isomorphy but helps e.g. in $p$-groups.

**1) In my opinion the serious thing:** You loose knowledge of the commutator map $G/G'\times G/G'\rightarrow G'/G^{(2)}$ and only preserve THAT elements appear as commutators.

Take as **example** the **extraspecial groups** $p^{2n+1}_\pm$ (such as the direct product with centers identified $D_4\ast\ldots\ast D_4$) compared to e.g. these one:  $p_\pm^{2\cdot 1+1}\times \mathbb{Z}_p^{2(n-1)}$  (such as $D_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2^{2(n-1)}$). Both are central/stem-extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{2n}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but the second is a lot "more commutative" ;-)

**2) A lot more tricky to detect but maybe not-so-serious:** Even if the commutator maps match, it remains unclear how elements powered-up/"fused" to the divided-out commutators.

Best **examples** are certainly the different extraspecials $p_+^{2\cdot n+1}$ vs. $p_-^{2\cdot n+1}$, especially $D_4$ vs. $Q_8$ (as Zhou said), that can only be distinguished by how many elements powering to the central commutator.

The latter behaviour is sometimes described as the groups being **isoclinic** (there are different definitions!) and this is also responsible e.g. for the three different nonabelian isomorphy types in order $2^n$. It is fairily mild and used e.g. in the classification efforts on $p$-groups. Most prominent examples you get from **different Schur covers** of a group being isoclinic (again $D_4/Q_8$ but also the different 2-covers of $S_n$). In this situation by construction all isoclinics are **isomorphic as grouprings** $k[D_4]\cong k[Q_8]$ and hence have the **same representation theory**, although I have no sources confirming this for nonabelian extensions!!

**Hope that helps ;-)**